# Converting Data Table to List and vice versa

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datatable

I don't know what's wrong. I have a SQL Statement and an adapter

```
 DataTable datTableCur = new DataTable();
 datTable = new DataTable();

 sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT DISTINCT [" + form1.getCol() + "] FROM [" + form1.getTableName3() + "]", connection);
 sqlDatAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd.CommandText, connection);
 sqlDatAdapter.Fill(datTableCur);
```

Since the format is "float" in SQL I convert it to "Double" in C# and put every element of the column in a List

```
 List<Double> convertCol = new List<Double>();
 List<Double> convertedCol = new List<Double>();

 foreach (DataRow row in datTableCur.Rows)
 {
     convertCol.Add((double)row[0]);
 }
```

Now I want to check if the elements have "," and if that's the case I want to replace the "," with a ".", so I convert every single element into a String, check this case, replace the char, convert it back to Double and store it in another List

```
  String convertToString;
  Double storeDouble;
  Double convertBackToDouble;

  for (int i = 0; i < convertCol.Count; i++)
  {
      storeDouble = convertCol[i];
      convertToString = storeDouble.ToString("0.######");

      if (convertToString.Contains(","))
      {
          convertToString.Replace(",", ".");
          convertBackToDouble = Convert.ToDouble(convertToString);
          convertedCol.Add(convertBackToDouble);
      }
      else 
      {
          convertedCol.Add(convertCol[i]);
      }
  }
```

and now here's my problem. I want to put that back into a `DataTable`, and put that in a ListBoxbut that doesn't work. I get an ArgumentException and the error, that the input array is longer than the number of columns in the table.

```
datTable.Rows.Add(form1.getCol());

for (int j = 1; j < convertedCol.Count; j++)
{
    datTable.Rows.Add(convertedCol[j]);
}

form1.colList.DisplayMember = form1.getCol();
form1.colList.ValueMember = "Column";
form1.col.DataSource = datTable;
```

Comment: Why you again want to set in datatable and then assign to the listbox you can directly assign the `List<Double>` to the listbox ??

Comment: Because that would cause errors in another function. It would be better to fill the DataTable with the elements.

Comment: You can use datatable where you want the unaltered values and list where you want updated values .

Comment: I just want to fill the "convertedCol" list with the entries (hope the code should be right) and add the columnname on the first place. When I fill the dataTable without the line "datTable.Rows.Add(form1.getCol());" he doesn't find the column (because the name doesn't appear in the List). When I try it like above I get the Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are facing due to you need to add the `column` first in the `datatable` you are adding or to replace the precious orignal value column you need to add the column with same name

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("col2");
dc.DataType = typeof(double);
table.Columns.Remove("col2");
table.Columns.Add(dc);
```

and you can set the values then.

You can shorten your loop like below to get your list of double values.(Not tested may have syntax error).

```
var result doubleValueList = dt.AsEnumerable()
         .Select(x=> new {double.Parse(x.ToString("0.######").Replace(",", "."))})
         .ToList();
```

Comment: That helped! Thank you! - I just had to delete the "Remove" function

Comment: I don't know if I should make a new Thread for this. In the conversion function where I convert the String back to a double he saves the wrong value. String is "0.09" and I get "9.0" as a Double...

Comment: Yes make a new thread For this. This is entirely different issue.